# How to make dynamic variable to check array with .every

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-programming

For a project we need to check if all numbers in a card, match another card with drawn numbers.
When hardcoded with a const checkCard = card001 it goes well with .every.
When trying to choose the card a dynamic way, pulling the number from a localStorage (e.g. const card = 'card'+cardNumber), an error pops up with t.every is not a function.
The question: how to make this dynamic. We hope someone is able to help to overcome this issue.

```
checkCard = () => {
    var cardNumber = localStorage.cardNumber;
   
    const card001 = [14, 4, 10, 8, 12, 30, 28, 23, 16, 27, 41, 35, 43, 39, 53, 57, 46, 48, 56, 74, 68, 75, 70, 66]
    const card002 = [15, 13, 8, 1, 12, 26, 20, 19, 28, 24, 38, 42, 33, 41, 59, 53, 60, 55, 51, 68, 62, 71, 70, 65]
    const card003 = [11, 5, 4, 13, 9, 23, 27, 16, 18, 26, 44, 38, 40, 36, 53, 47, 56, 55, 50, 69, 65, 63, 61, 74]

    const previousCallList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.previousCallList));
    console.log('previousCallList: ', previousCallList)
    const previousCallListNumber =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.previousCallListNumber));
    console.log('previousCallListNumber: ', previousCallListNumber)

    //const card = 'card'+cardNumber;
    const checkCard = card001

    const checkDrawn = previousCallListNumber ;
    const containsAll = checkCard .every(element => {
      return checkDrawn.includes(element);
    });
    console.log(containsAll); // ️ true

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between these two lines:

```
// Point `checkCard` to the current array stored in `card001`
const checkCard = card001

// Point `checkCard` to a string "card001"
const checkCard = "card001"
```

When you write `'card'+cardNumber`, you're creating a new *string*, not a reference to another variable.

If you want to dynamically pick a variable based on its name, you can define named properties on an object. For example:

```js
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};


console.log(
  myObject["a"],
  myObject["b"],
  myObject["c"]
)
```

Or, with your data:

```js
const cardNumber = "001";
   
const card001 = [14, 4, 10, 8, 12, 30, 28, 23, 16, 27, 41, 35, 43, 39, 53, 57, 46, 48, 56, 74, 68, 75, 70, 66]
const card002 = [15, 13, 8, 1, 12, 26, 20, 19, 28, 24, 38, 42, 33, 41, 59, 53, 60, 55, 51, 68, 62, 71, 70, 65]
const card003 = [11, 5, 4, 13, 9, 23, 27, 16, 18, 26, 44, 38, 40, 36, 53, 47, 56, 55, 50, 69, 65, 63, 61, 74]

const cardVarName = "card" + cardNumber;
log(cardVarName); // This is now the string "card001", not a reference to the card001 variable


// Store the cards in an object
const cards = { card001, card002, card003 };
// Reference a card using obj[propertyName]
log(cards[cardVarName])


function log(x) { console.log(JSON.stringify(x)); }
```

Comment: That worked great ....  Thank you so much for your reply and this little lesson!

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use `localStorage` you need to familiarize yourself with the syntax, what you have now...

```
localStorage.cardNumber;
```

...should've given you an error. The following are two functions that get and set data to and from `localStorage`:

```
/*
>key< is a string assigned as an id to stored data.
If there isn't anything stored an empty array is returned/
*/
const getLS = key => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];
/*
>key< is same as above. >data< is the value that needs to 
be stored.
*/
const setLS = (key, data) => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
```

Note that `LS` only stores strings which is why `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` are used on the data. In the example the
lines concerning `LS` are commented out because SO snippets prohibit them -- just uncomment them when you test them in a normal environment.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
// Utility function
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

//const getLS = key => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];

//const setLS = (key, data) => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));

/*
All arrays as parameters so function can be reusable
*/
const deckA = [14, 4, 10, 8, 12, 30, 28, 23, 16, 27, 41, 35, 43, 39, 53, 57, 46, 48, 56, 74, 68, 75, 70, 66];
const deckB = [15, 13, 8, 1, 12, 26, 20, 19, 28, 24, 38, 42, 33, 41, 59, 53, 60, 55, 51, 68, 62, 71, 70, 65];
const deckC = [11, 5, 4, 13, 9, 23, 27, 16, 18, 26, 44, 38, 40, 36, 53, 47, 56, 55, 50, 69, 65, 63, 61, 74];

/**
 * find match between a given number and a
 * number from one or more given arrays
 * @param {number} card = Number to find
 * @param {arrays} cards = One or more arrays
 * @returns {array<object>} Each object is
 *  created like this:
 *  {card: 55, row: 2, col: 17}
 *  "card 55 is in the 3rd array index 17"
 */
const findMatch = (card, ...cards) => {
  //const data = getLS('cards');
  //data.push(card);
  //setLS('cards', data);
  
  // Gather ...cards into an array:
  // [ [deckA], [deckB], [deckC] ]
  const decks = [...cards];
  /*
  First, .map() runs through each sub-array and
  .flatMap() compares each number of each sub-
  array vs. card. If there's a match, return
  a new object (see above) otherwise an empty
  array is returned
  */
  return decks.map((sub, row) => sub.flatMap((num, col) => num === card ? {card: card, row: row, col: col} : [])).flat();
};

log(findMatch(55, deckA, deckB, deckC));
log(findMatch(3, deckA, deckB, deckC));
log(findMatch(25, deckA, deckB, deckC));
log(findMatch(13, deckA, deckB, deckC));
```